# Does a VOB replica name uniquely identify a replica in ClearCase?

Tags: clearcase

We need to create a new ClearCase site with a subset of our original VOBs.
The new site should have the same sitename somewhere down the line as the old one currently, as the old one will be shut down.
While developers are still working with the old replicas, the new replicas go by a temporary name and no work takes place on them.
The goal is to later rename the new replicas to the old name, once the old VOBs are shut down, with the developers being able to continue work on their old branches as if nothing had happened.

The issue is that there are hundreds of branch types created on the old replicas, all mastered by them.
While `cleartool chmaster` can be used to change the mastership of individual branches, when branching from an exisiting element, we need to make sure that the new replica of the respective containing VOB masters the branch type.

Since the mastership of branch types can not be changed, our only hope is if renaming the new VOB replicas to the old name causes the branch types to accept the new VOBs as their masters.
Visibility is not an issue, as the new VOB replicas already see the old branches, they are synchronized.

So does changing the replica of a VOB hosted by a ClearCase server to that of a previously existing VOB hosted by another, previous ClearCase server cause the new VOB replicas to master branch types created in the previous VOB replicas? 
Or is there some underlying ID that will not match the mastership of the old branch types, even if the replica matches their masterships by name?